# I installed ubuntu from wubi alonside win8 can i get the gnu grub insted of the win8 bootloder

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, wubi, windows-8

hi i have successfully installed Ubuntu alongside win8 (using wubi). I installed Ubuntu on a separate hard drive but the win8 bootloder is slow. Can i get grub in some way?

I have attempted booting of the disk Ubuntu was installed on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Wubi you cannot get rid of the Win bootloader.

A Wubi install means Ubuntu is installed inside Windows, so during the boot process the Windows bootloader must be loaded first anyway. Then, it can load Grub, but you cannot load Grub without loading the Win bootloader first.